# Is "he has to eat more" a complete sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this a complete sentence? It has both a noun and a verb, but I am unsure if it expresses a complete thought.

It seems to me that *more* is modifying a noun that is missing from the sentence. He has to eat more... *what?*. That is the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a complete sentence.  "He has to eat" would itself be a complete sentence, with "more" just a simple adverb to modify *how* his eating habits should change. A similar example:

> She has to **study more** (if she wants to get better grades).

It's not necessary to specify what she should *study*.  "More" by itself implies the general "more often", or "for longer periods of time", or even "more assiduously".

Of course it's also possible to specify exactly *what* he should eat more *of*, which as you say would modify the defined noun:

> The doctor said he has to eat more **fruit and vegetables**.